# Before_validation :set_locale vs I18n.t(text: ..., locale: )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dry, rails-i18n, setlocale

What is better to you ?

- precise the locale in all I18n.t(....) messages of the page, or
- set_locale in a before_validation logic ?

I'm concern about DRY but also performance.

Answer (score 2):

You should save your locale in your session and set it by default at your application starting.

I recommend you to read this article : [best practices](https://phraseapp.com/blog/posts/rails-i18n-best-practices/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use both methods to implement i18n in Rails application.

1. Set locale in a before_action of controller.(ref: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)
2. Use I18n.t() to translate text according to the current locale.