# How I can using route-translator gem for using in link tag in html(between <a></a> tag)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rubygems, translation

I used https://github.com/enriclluelles/route_translator gem in my project for translating routes. But according to locale language I want to get path in

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href=""></a>
```

html `<a>` tags . How can I give path for  tag in href ?

Answer (score 0):

1. First you need to set correct locale of user(ref: [Before_validation :set_locale vs I18n.t(text: ..., locale: )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46768580/before-validation-set-locale-vs-i18n-ttext-locale/46769672#46769672))
2. Then add to your view: `= link_to 'Localized path', url_for(locale: I18n.locale)`